# How to delete an element from an array in C#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Lets say I have this array,

```
int[] numbers = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2};
```

How can I delete an element by "name"? , lets say number 4?

Even `ArrayList` didn't help to delete?

```
string strNumbers = " 1, 3, 4, 9, 2";
ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList(strNumbers.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
numbers.RemoveAt(numbers.IndexOf(4));
foreach (var n in numbers)
{
    Response.Write(n);
}
```

Comment: What if you have duplicate values in your list?  Do you want just to remove the first instance or all of the instances?

Comment: yes, I don't have duplicate values, any idea?

Comment: ahmed Do you mean, No you do not, or yes you do? (not insulting your english, just asking for clarification)

Comment: @Malfist - sorry :), I meant I don't care about duplicated values because I am sure there are not any of them in my case, thanks again

Comment: You cannot remove items from arrays in C#, as you can see from [this example program](http://ideone.com/bKtZW4). What you can do is create a new array, copy only some of the elements of the original one and assign it back to the original variable. This is what is done in all the answers.

Comment: If you don't need to remove an arbitrary item but suppose you wanted to pop the leading item, you can use c# directly now `var tail = numbers[1..]`

Answer (score 434, accepted):

***If you want to remove all instances of 4 without needing to know the index:***

***LINQ:*** (.NET Framework 3.5)

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2 };
int numToRemove = 4;
numbers = numbers.Where(val => val != numToRemove).ToArray();
```

***Non-LINQ:*** (.NET Framework 2.0)

```
static bool isNotFour(int n)
{
    return n != 4;
}

int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2 };
numbers = Array.FindAll(numbers, isNotFour).ToArray();
```

***If you want to remove just the first instance:***

***LINQ:*** (.NET Framework 3.5)

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 4 };
int numToRemove = 4;
int numIndex = Array.IndexOf(numbers, numToRemove);
numbers = numbers.Where((val, idx) => idx != numIndex).ToArray();
```

***Non-LINQ:*** (.NET Framework 2.0)

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 4 };
int numToRemove = 4;
int numIdx = Array.IndexOf(numbers, numToRemove);
List<int> tmp = new List<int>(numbers);
tmp.RemoveAt(numIdx);
numbers = tmp.ToArray();
```

***Edit:*** Just in case you hadn't already figured it out, as Malfist pointed out, you need to be targetting the .NET Framework 3.5 in order for the LINQ code examples to work.  If you're targetting 2.0 you need to reference the Non-LINQ examples.

Answer (score 44):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2 };
numbers = numbers.Except(new int[]{4}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 35):

You can also convert your array to a list and call remove on the list. You can then convert back to your array.

```
int[] numbers = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2};
var numbersList = numbers.ToList();
numbersList.Remove(4);
```

Comment: numbersList.Remove(4);
has to be:
numbersList.RemoveAt(4);

Comment: @Deniz \*Yoda voice\* Closer look, my friend. To the array there is more than you see. Valid both are, `numbersList.Remove(4)` and `numbersList.RemoveAt(4)`! But the same result, they do not give.

Answer (score 12):

The code that is written in the question has a bug in it

Your arraylist contains strings of " 1" " 3" " 4" " 9" and " 2" (note the spaces)

So IndexOf(4) will find nothing because 4 is an int, and even "tostring" would convert it to of "4" and not " 4", and nothing will get removed.

An arraylist is the correct way to go to do what you want.

Comment: List<T> would be better than ArrayList.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes.  While I absolutely agree with @MikeScott that `List<T>` would be better than ArrayList, this seems to be the only answer that correctly identifies the problem that the OP had when he tried to use ArrayList to solve his original problem.  The OP understood that you can't resize arrays, which nobody else seems to have noticed, and tried to use a resizeable type instead, which nobody else seems to have noticed, and then got tripped up by a different problem, which nobody else seems to have noticed.

Answer (score 10):

I posted my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array/17841639#17841639).

This is a way to delete an array element without copying to another array - just in frame of the same array instance:

```
    public static void RemoveAt<T>(ref T[] arr, int index)
    {
        for (int a = index; a < arr.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            // moving elements downwards, to fill the gap at [index]
            arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
        }
        // finally, let's decrement Array's size by one
        Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Resize actually copies the data to a new array (unless the passed new size is the length of the passed array); it doesn't change the size of the passed array instance.  That's why it's a reference parameter.  See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/71074deaf111c4e3.html.

Answer (score 7):

Removing from an array itself is not simple, as you then have to deal with resizing.  This is one of the great advantages of using something like a `List<int>` instead.  It provides `Remove`/`RemoveAt` in 2.0, and lots of LINQ extensions for 3.0.

If you can, refactor to use a `List<>` or similar.

Comment: I think it's the best solution in this case.

Comment: It is a duplicate of Dave Dp answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4493444/52277

Answer (score 6):

Balabaster's answer is correct if you want to remove all instances of the element. If you want to remove only the first one, you would do something like this:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2, 4 };
int numToRemove = 4;
int firstFoundIndex = Array.IndexOf(numbers, numToRemove);
if (numbers >= 0)
{
    numbers = numbers.Take(firstFoundIndex).Concat(numbers.Skip(firstFoundIndex + 1)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As a generic extension, 2.0-compatible:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public static class Extensions {
    //=========================================================================
    // Removes all instances of [itemToRemove] from array [original]
    // Returns the new array, without modifying [original] directly
    // .Net2.0-compatible
    public static T[] RemoveFromArray<T> (this T[] original, T itemToRemove) {  
        int numIdx = System.Array.IndexOf(original, itemToRemove);
        if (numIdx == -1) return original;
        List<T> tmp = new List<T>(original);
        tmp.RemoveAt(numIdx);
        return tmp.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 3, 4, 9, 2};
numbers = numbers.RemoveFromArray(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do in this way:

```
int[] numbers= {1,3,4,9,2};     
List<int> lst_numbers = new List<int>(numbers);
int required_number = 4;
int i = 0;
foreach (int number in lst_numbers)
{              
    if(number == required_number)
    {
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
lst_numbers.RemoveAt(i);
numbers = lst_numbers.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

' **To remove items from string based on Dictionary key values.**
' VB.net code

```
 Dim stringArr As String() = "file1,file2,file3,file4,file5,file6".Split(","c)
 Dim test As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
 test.Add("file3", "description")
 test.Add("file5", "description")
 stringArr = stringArr.Except(test.Keys).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public int[] DeletePart(int position, params int[] numbers)
    {
        int[] result = new int[numbers.Length - 1];
        int z=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (position - 1 != i)
            {
                result[z] = numbers[i];
                z++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In recent C#/.NET featuring the `Span<T>` type and range expressions this can be done using the `Span.CopyTo` method to move array elements around:

```cs
// Removes a[i..i+n], fast but not preserving the order of array elements.
void arrayRemoveAtFast<T>(ref T[] a, int i, int n)
{
    // Create a Span that references the array elements.
    var s = a.AsSpan();
    // Copy the last n array elements to positions i…i+n.
    // Caveat: Use `s`, not `a`, or else the result may be invalid.
    s[^n..].CopyTo(s[i..(i+n)]);
    // Cut the last n array elements off.
    a = a[..^n];
}

// Removes a[i..i+n], preserving the order of array elements.
void arrayRemoveAtPreserveOrder<T>(ref T[] a, int i, int n)
{
    // Create a Span that references the array elements.
    var s = a.AsSpan();
    // Move array elements that follow the ones to remove to the front.
    // Caveat: Use `s`, not `a`, or else the result may be invalid.
    s[(i + n)..].CopyTo(s[i..^n]);
    // Cut the last n array elements off.
    a = a[..^n];
}
```

Answer (score -6):

We can delete array elements by using `for` loops and `continue` statements:

```cs
string[] cars = {"volvo", "benz", "ford", "bmw"};
for (int i = 0; i < cars.Length; i++)
{
    if (cars[i] == "benz")
    {
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(cars[i]);
}
```

Comment: That does not change the array in anyway.

Comment: This removes an element from an array in the same way that covering up your eyes removes a baby from the room.

Comment: delete an element that we won't display in output. your right, that doesnt change the array in reality.