# How to remove elements from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-2.0

Hi I'm working on some legacy code that goes something along the lines of

```
for(int i = results.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(someCondition)
  {
     results.Remove(results[i]);
  }
}
```

To me it seems like bad practice to be removing the elements while still iterating through the loop because you'll be modifying the indexes.

Is this a correct assumption?

Is there a better way of doing this? I would like to use LINQ but I'm  in 2.0 Framework

Comment: yeah, actually you cannot do that. It should throw an exception.

Comment: It works until by removing a result you shorten the length of an array and then you try to access something outside of the array.

Comment: [redacted] actually, nothing about that code makes much sense. ;-\

Comment: Does the code work?  How would you rather do it?  I've used this method, so I'm interested to know if it is "bad practice."

Comment: @Victor - If it *should* throw an exception it *would*.

Comment: @spencer. Ha! yeah I missed the backwards loop. oops

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete an element from an array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The removal is actually ok since you are going downwards to zero, only the indexes that you already passed will be modified. This code actually would break for another reason: It starts with `results.Count`, but should start at `results.Count -1` since array indexes start at 0.

```
for(int i = results.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(someCondition)
  {
     results.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

As was pointed out - you actually must be dealing with a List of some sort in your pseudo-code. In this case they are conceptually the same (since Lists use an Array internally) but if you use an array you have a `Length` property (instead of a `Count` property) and you can not add or remove items.

Using a list the solution above is certainly concise but might not be easy to understand for someone that has to maintain the code (i.e. especially iterating through the list backwards) - an alternative solution could be to first identify the items to remove, then in a second pass removing those items.

Just substitute `MyType` with the actual type you are dealing with:

```
List<MyType> removeItems = new List<MyType>();

foreach(MyType item in results)
{
   if(someCondition)
   {
        removeItems.Add(item);
   }
}

foreach (MyType item in removeItems)
    results.Remove(item);
```

Comment: I was surprised more people hadn't mentioned that it's iterating backwards. +1

Comment: Yes, it does need what you suggested. I missed that out. Updated.

Comment: At this point, why not call RemoveAt?  The index is already provided.

Comment: BrokenGlass, your alternative approach converts original O(n) code to O(n^2) as Remove have to search through whole list.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov - that is true, I still find it easier to comprehend though than the first approach (even if it's not as concise and performant). Having said that, if OP's list truly contains a large number of items it's definitely a point to consider - performance vs clarity of intend.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest a somewhat more functional alternative to your current code:

Instead of modifying the existing array one item at a time, you could derive a new one from it and then replace the whole array as an "atomic" operation once you're done:

**The easy way (no LINQ, but very similar):**

```
Predicate<T> filter = delegate(T item) { return !someCondition; };

results = Array.FindAll(results, filter);
// with LINQ, you'd have written: results = results.Where(filter);
```

where `T` is the type of the items in your `results` array.

---

**A somewhat more explicit alternative:**

```
var newResults = new List<T>();
foreach (T item in results)
{
    if (!someCondition)
    {
        newResults.Add(item);
    }
}
results = newResults.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like the Remove should work at all.  The IList implementation should fail if we're dealing with a fixed-size array, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345438.aspx).

That being said, if you're dealing with a resizable list (e.g. List<T>), why call Remove instead of RemoveAt?  Since you're already navigating the indices in reverse, you don't need to "re-find" the item.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you wouldn't remove elements as such, you would create a new array from the old without the unwanted elements.

If you do go the route of removing elements from an array/list your loop should count down rather than up. (as yours does)

Answer (score 0):

a couple of options:

```
List<int> indexesToRemove = new List<int>();
for(int i = results.Count; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(someCondition)
  {
     //results.Remove(results[i]);
       indexesToRemove.Add(i);
  }
}

foreach(int i in indexesToRemove) {
results.Remove(results[i]);
}
```

or alternatively, you could make a copy of the existing list, and instead remove from the original list.

```
//temp is a copy of results
for(int i = temp.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  if(someCondition)
  {
     results.Remove(results[i]);
  }
}
```