# C# remove elements in list starting with #

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868035/how-to-remove-elements-from-an-array)

I have an List with a bunch of data in it. Some of the lines start with a `#`. I want to remove those lines.

How...?

Comment: That one specifies .net 2.0 in the question, this doesn't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

assuming its a string List

```
myList.RemoveAll(x => x.BeginsWith("#"));
```

Comment: Even better.  I'll remove mine.