# C# Remove items from class array

Tags: c#, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove element of a regular array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array)

I have a method defined which returns class array.
ex: Sampleclass[]
The Sampleclass has properties Name, Address, City, Zip. On the client side I wanted to loop through the array and remove unwanted items. I am able to loop thru, but not sure how to remove the item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Sampleclass.Length; i++)
{
if (Sampleclass[i].Address.Contains(""))
{ 
**// How to remove ??**
}
}
```

Comment: Already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c

Comment: you might want to rething the *remove everything whose Address* `.Contains("")` statement in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are fixed size and don't allow you to remove items once allocated - for this you can use `List<T>` instead. Alternatively you could use Linq to filter and project to a new array:

```
var filteredSampleArray = Sampleclass.Where( x => !x.Address.Contains(someString))
                                     .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to remove from an array in this fashion. Arrays are statically allocated collections who's size doesn't change.  You need to use a collection like `List<T>` instead.  With `List<T>` you could do the following

```
var i = 0;
while (i < Sampleclass.Count) {
  if (Sampleclass[i].Address.Contains("")) {
    Sampleclass.RemoveAt(i);
  } else {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: @StriplingWarrior updated to reflect OP should be using `List<T>` vs. an array

Comment: I don't see a 'RemoveAt' option. Don't know why!