# how to join two out of three values of an array

Tags: c#

I have spilt one value in an array into 3 different values in a new array.

```
string [] names = new string[2];
names = oldcolumns[0].Split(' ');
```

I now want to be able to join names[1] and names[2] together.
I have tried several different ways and cant seem to get it working.

This is an example of what I have tried

```
output = String.Concat(names[1], names[2]);
```

Comment: Don't forget about 0-indexing! Either make the names-array larger (3), or use names[0] and names[1]. Well, the output from the Split overrides the array so no need to initialize it at size (anything).

Comment: I have a names[0] but I dont want to join it

Comment: `String output = names[1] + names[2]` ?

Comment: What do you mean can't seem to get it working?  What inputs have you tried and what output are you getting?  Are you receiving an error?

Comment: You can concatenate strings with `var foobar = "foo" + "bar"`.

Comment: Or you can event remove item from array: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp and do what you need, or use linq (same link)

Comment: The first assignment (names = `new string[2]`) is useless. (and also wrong; it would create an array of length 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one statement, using `string.Join`

```
var result = string.Join(" ", oldcolumns[0].Split(' ').Skip(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] names = "Mr James Bond".Split(' ');
string output = names[1] + " " + names[2];
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output: James Bond

Comment: I get an error saying index was outside the bounds of the array when I tried this

Comment: Well, in that case your input string doesn't have enough spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `string.Format`

```
output = String.Format("{0} {1}",names[1], names[2]);
```

Comment: I get an error saying index was outside the bounds of the array when I tried this

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
output  = String.Join(" ", new String[]{names[1], names[2]});
```

[image]