# Improve performance of code

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, generics

Requirement:I have two string array. Array of empDetails contain four field assume field one is ID and other fields are details. Array of empToRemove contain IDs of employee to remove. Create string of array which will not contain IDs which are present in empToRomove array. Please note I have to use this code which contain more than 100000 data in empDetails and more then 20000 data in empToRemove.
Any suggestion much appropriated.

```
string[] empDetails = { "1,abc,2,11k", "2,de,3,11k", "3,abc,2,18k", "4,abdc,2,12k" };

string[] empToRemove = { "1","3" };
```

My Solution

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] empDetails = { "1,abc,2,11k", "2,de,3,11k", "3,abc,2,18k", "4,abdc,2,12k" };

        string[] empToRemove = { "1","3" };

        //Add emp details in list of employee
        List<emp> e = new List<emp>();
        foreach (var item in empDetails)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> tempEmployee = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string details in item.Split(','))
            {
                tempEmployee.Add(i, details);
                i++;
            }
            e.Add(new emp { ID = int.Parse(tempEmployee[1]), Details1 = tempEmployee[2], Details2 = tempEmployee[3], Details3 = tempEmployee[4] });
        }
        foreach (string item in empToRemove)
        {
            emp employeeToRemove = e.Where(x => x.ID == int.Parse(item)).Single();
            e.Remove(employeeToRemove);
        }
        foreach (var item in e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ID + item.Details1 + item.Details2 + item.Details3);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class emp
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Details1 { get; set; }
    public string Details2 { get; set; }
    public string Details3 { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If it works you need to post this on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Every heard of a database? They are designed to do exactly this.

Comment: or this `empDetails = empDetails.ToList().Select(val => val.Split(new char[] { ',' })).ToList().Where(val => !empToRemove.Contains(val[0])).ToList().Select(val => string.Join(",", val)).ToArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood your requirement and the only thing you need - is to print (or manipulate somehow else) elements of empDetails which ID's not in empToRemove - than your code is totally overkill.
Following will be pretty sufficient:

```
string[] empDetails = { "1,abc,2,11k", "2,de,3,11k", "3,abc,2,18k", "4,abdc,2,12k" };
string[] empToRemove = { "1", "3" };

var remove = new HashSet<string>(empToRemove);
foreach (var item in empDetails)
{
    string id = item.Substring(0, item.IndexOf(','));
    if (!remove.Contains(id))
        Console.WriteLine(item); // or your custom action with this item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] empDetails = { "1,abc,2,11k", "2,de,3,11k", "3,abc,2,18k", "4,abdc,2,12k" };
    string[] empToRemove = { "1","3" };

    foreach (string item in empToRemove)        
      empDetails = empDetails.Where(val => val.Substring(0, val.IndexOf(',')) != item).ToArray();
```

Is one way. Cant get more effeciant than that?

based on research from:

[How to delete an element from an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp][1])

Comment: does now. forgot to get the sub string

Comment: @ravenx30 Still does not. What about ID's greater than 9?

Comment: @ravenx30 And if we are talking about performance - your code is at least N times slower then suggested by me, where N is the size of empToRemove array. That's because your code executes linq where method on empDetails N times, and each call will take O(M) time, where M is the size of empDetails. LINQ is a very good thing, but not a "silver bullet" and should be used reasonably.

Comment: fixed with four lines of code.. uses less memory and loops though a smaller array (emp to remove)

Comment: @ravenx30 Read my previous comment carefully. Your solution actually does N loops through empDetails, where N is size of empToRemove. Each LINQ call to "where" in your cycle will result to loop through all elements of empDetails.

Comment: Both our answers perform similarly as both arrays have to be looped.. Just he tagged this Linq so gave an answer using that. But still believe my solution will work faster.. As you are having to create a HashSet to check against while I do not.. and surly the foreach loop uses more processing power than a Linx Where clause?