# Cropping lines and columns in String[n,m] C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a 'matrix' of strings that I saved as a String[m,n] object (an array of arrays of strings, I believe, whith m lines and n columns).

I would like to know the best way to crop a whole line or a whole column of that array of arrays.

For example, what is the best way to remove all m=1 indexed entries (the second line of the matrix), such that the third line automatically becomes the second, end the fourth becomes the third and so forward...).

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it for a game, accounting application? And what have you tried already and hasn't worked?

Comment: If you need to modify it use a `List<List<string>>` instead. Then removing a "line" becomes trivial. But removing a "column" is a bit more work. You need to loop the list and use [`List.RemoveAt(index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) on every nested list.

Comment: The `[m, n]` index notation indicates a [multidimentional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx), not an "array of arrays" or a "jagged array" as it's also referred to

Comment: I am trying to turn a filter/dynamic table operational work (previously done in excel) in an automatic process. For that I have to remove certain lines that correspond to data I must not use. I wanted to use String[n,m] because it seemed simpler and most intuitive to work with, since it is not a complex data processing.

Comment: In what way is a two-dimensional array, which does not inherently support the operations you seem to want to use, "simpler and most intuitive" as compared to using `List<List<string>>` (as suggested above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keywords `rows`, `columns`, `excel table` gave me a hint

there is `DataTable` class in `System.Data` namespace, which can do almost all what you are asking about (except that it contains values of `object` type, not `string`).

example

```
int cols = 100;
int rows = 500;
System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    dt.Columns.Add("col_" + c);

for(int r=0; r<rows; r++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add();
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        dt.Rows[r][c] = String.Format("({0}:{1})", r, c);
}
```

how to get values?

```
string value_row2_colum_5 = dt.Rows[2].Field<string>(5);
string value_row20_colum_50 = dt.Rows[20][50].ToString();
```

how to set values?

```
dt.Rows[2][5] = "set";
```

how to remove column?

DataTable has `Columns` property. you can remove any of them, e.g.

```
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

how to remove row?

DataTable has `Rows` property. you can remove any of them, e.g.

```
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

also DataTable has `Select` and `Compute` methods which are very helpful in some cases

Answer (score 2):

From my comment: If you need to modify it use a `List<List<string>>` instead since arrays have a fixed size. Then removing a "line" becomes trivial. But removing a "column" is a bit more work. You need to loop the list and use [`List.RemoveAt(index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) on every nested list.

Here's an example.

```
int rows = 10; int columns = 5;
List<List<string>> lines = new List<List<string>>(rows);
for (int row = 1; row <= rows; row++)
{
    List<string> fields = new List<string>(columns);
    for (int col = 1; col <= columns; col++)
        fields.Add(string.Format("row{0},col{1}", row, col));
    lines.Add(fields);
}
```

This list contains 10 lists and each inner list contains 5 strings. Now it's easy to remove the second "line":

```
lines.RemoveAt(1);
```

or to remove  the second "column":

```
foreach (List<string> line in lines)
    line.RemoveAt(1);
```

The resulting list without the seond line and second column:

```
foreach (List<string> line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" | ", line));

row1,col1 | row1,col3 | row1,col4 | row1,col5
row3,col1 | row3,col3 | row3,col4 | row3,col5
row4,col1 | row4,col3 | row4,col4 | row4,col5
row5,col1 | row5,col3 | row5,col4 | row5,col5
row6,col1 | row6,col3 | row6,col4 | row6,col5
row7,col1 | row7,col3 | row7,col4 | row7,col5
row8,col1 | row8,col3 | row8,col4 | row8,col5
row9,col1 | row9,col3 | row9,col4 | row9,col5
row10,col1 | row10,col3 | row10,col4 | row10,col5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think RemoveAt method should do the work for you. Just simply go through your Array in a loop.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Did you mean to reference [this specific answer]http://stackoverflow.com/a/17841729/3538012) instead of the whole question?

Comment: Yes, I meant to reference the usage of RemoveAt in that comment.