# Removing values from string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, text-files, streamreader

I have 150,000 line text file which is being stored as a String Array as such:

```
String[] OutputArray = File.ReadAllLines(TB_Complete.Text);
```

How can I remove a specified list of lines from OutputArray? Or better yet how could I remove the first 1000 lines of OutputArray?

*EDIT: I need the first 1000 lines to be read, parsed, output into another text file, AND THEN deleted. Sorry I didn't clarify.

Comment: By not reading those first 1000 lines in the first place

Comment: Do you really need to read 150k lines into an array? That is usually a very bad idea compared, for example, to `foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1000)) {...}`, which would stream the data without loading it all at once?

Comment: You should think about using `List<T>` instead. it is much easier to use for arrays imo.

Comment: I need them to be read, stored&output into another text file, and then removed as stated above.

Comment: @JohnOdom there are very few semantic differences - and certainly not any that would be useful in this context

Comment: @ErickAlfaro and what part of that requires them to be in an array?

Comment: @MarcGravell Well what do you suggest instead?

Comment: What do you do with those lines? What happens to the first 1000 and the rest? Do you immediately store them again?

Comment: @ErickAlfaro a number of things come to mind, but IMO it still isn't actually clearly defined yet - forget the array: that is an implementation detail - but it is still not clear to me what your desired inputs and outputs are here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `ReadLines()` instead as it returns an `IEnumerable<string>` and then skip the first 1000 rows.

```
String[] OutputArray = File.ReadLines(TB_Complete.Text).Skip(1000).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Alex it doesn't do that; `ReadLines` is non-buffered

Comment: oops, my mistake, I read this as also containing the `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: It doesn't allocate 2 x 150,000 strings but one. But still the question is whether OP really needs this?

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify. I need the first 1000 lines to be read, parsed, output into another text file, AND THEN deleted.

Comment: @ErickAlfaro deleted from the *file*? or from the array? are the other 140k lines needed in memory? sorry to be picky, but details are *everything* in questions like this

Comment: @MarcGravell To be specific: I am reading 150k lines, extracting necessary info, and outputting to another text file. Unfortunately 150k lines runs very slowly which has me looking for alternate solutions such as deleting lines that have already been read in the array so there is no unnecessary looping.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need the first 1000 lines to do one thing, and the remaining lines to do something else; I would *try* and do this without the overhead of holding everything in memory, so how about:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path)) {
    if(index++ < 1000) {
        // this is one of the first 1000 lines;
        DoA(line);
    } else {
        // this is one of the other lines
        DoB(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the additional info the op has given, it looks like the base problem is loading 150k lines of text at once, so this is definitely the preferred answer to that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is how to delete an array element from an array, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp) post could be useful although not efficient in your case.

Have you thing to use a more suitable data structure?
For example a `LIST<T>` ?
Elements deletion is easy and very efficient in Lists.

Comment: Deletion from the start of a list is *not* efficient - *at all*; you still need to do a memory-copy of the remaining data. And even that assumes you use `RemoveRange` rather than individual removal, which would be *catastrophically* bad. Using `List<T>` achieves very little over arrays - it isn't a magic bullet. Don't get me wrong - I would quite possibly use a `List<T>` here; but it wouldn't be the thing that changes it from hard to easy.

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree, I did not say that is easy or that `List<T>` is a magic bullet. I know that remove method is an O(n) operation but in this specific problem with this specific numbers (150.000 elements with 1000 deletions) I suppose that the performance is no so big problem. In addition the `RemoveRange` is not atall a bad approach, since memory-copy is sometimes the 'best' solution... ;|

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the whole file in
2. Pull a copy of the 1st 1000 lines
3. Parse/process those 1000 lines
4. Remove the 1000 lines from your original array
5. Write your file back out (I assume this when you said delete them)

   ```
       List<string> outputArray = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
       List<string> first1000Lines = outputArray.Take(1000).ToList();

       // Do what you need to do with first1000Lines

       outputArray.RemoveRange(0, 1000);

       File.WriteAllLines(filePath, outputArray);
   ```

Instead of RemoveRange, you could also use Skip.

```
File.WriteAllLines(filePath, outputArray.Skip(1000));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll try to see how I could implement this on my code. Here's the exact code I am trying to simplify. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779836/comparing-2-text-files-and-outputting-to-3rd-text-file-need-code-revision-co

Comment: You're welcome...  If this isn't what you're looking for, provide more clarification in your question.

Answer (score -1):

"How can I remove a specified list of lines from OutputArray?"

```
var removeTheseLines= new string[5];
var lines = new string[10];

var filterLines = lines.Except(removeTheseLines).ToArray();
```

Comment: I suspect we can assume that "the first 1000 lines" means: skip 1000 lines - not "ignore all occurrences of whatever happens to be in the first 1000 lines"; I don't think `Except` is a good option here

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify. I need the first 1000 lines to be read, parsed, output into another text file, AND THEN deleted.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: TBH, judging from the poster's edits, I am not sure anyone knows what is required. I am giving up on this one.

Comment: @Erick Alfaro: I anticipate repeated requests for clarification. I bow out now, rather than later.

Comment: @MarcGravell I posted a much more detailed question earlier bt received no responses. I figured I would dumb it down. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779836/comparing-2-text-files-and-outputting-to-3rd-text-file-need-code-revision-co