# How to delete an element of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I know this topic name is similar to another topic but that topic doesn't have the answers i wanted, so...

## 1st Question:

Let me say i have an array of:

```
string[] test = new string[5];
for(int x = 0; x <= test.Length - 1; x++)
{
    test[x] = "#" + (x + 1) + " element";
    Console.WriteLine(test[x]);
}

/*
output:
#1 element
#2 element
#3 element
#4 element
#5 element
*/
```

and say i wanted to remove "#4 element" from the string array, so that it instead outputs:

```
/*
output:
#1 element
#2 element
#3 element
#5 element
*/
```

how do i do that?

[PS:]The Answer i'm looking for is something that's easy to understand for a beginner.

Comment: It looks *remarkably* similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp?rq=1). If you think it's different, please explain *how* your question is different.

Comment: U can not do that in same array. U need to create the new one. For more info you can have a look on the link given by @demine.

Comment: Please check below post

[Remove Element of a regular array][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my question is different since i'm asking about `string`s instead of `int`s

Comment: It is not relevant if the array type is string or int, just the same behaviour. Also your '2nd Question' is completely different and does not match your title.

Comment: @Denis i removed it, because i knew it was off-topic and that i already knew how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete at particular index you can do as :

```
int[] numbers = { 1,2,3,4,5};
List<int> tmp = new List<int>(numbers);
tmp.RemoveAt(4);
numbers = tmp.ToArray();
```

But In your case since you are just expecting the element to be invisible and having the array length same :

```
string[] test = new string[5];
for(int x = 0; x <= test.Length - 1; x++)
{
    if(x!=3){
    test[x] = "#" + (x + 1) + " element";
    Console.WriteLine(test[x]);}
}
```

Comment: Whay a downVote? Please comment for the same :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `List<string>` rather than an array.
2. Use `list.RemoveAt(3)` to remove the forth element (elements start at 0)

So you might end up with something like the following in order to achieve you desired output:

```
var test = new List<string>();
for (var x = 1; x <= 5; x++)
{
    test.Add(String.Format("#{0} element", x));
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", test);

test.RemoveAt(3);
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", test);
```

Which will give you your desired output of:

`#1 element #2 element #3 element #4 element #5 element`

`#1 element #2 element #3 element #5 element`

Comment: how do i convert `list` to `string` so i can output it?

Answer (score 0):

You cant just delete an Element from an array, you only can set it to `""` for example.

Use `List<string>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Ans:**

You can use list or if you dont want to use list use **Linq** but it will create a different memory location for array and will store elements there(I suppose).
You can implement linq on your array as below:

```
test = test.Where(x => !x.Equals("#4 element")).ToArray();
//Print test Now
```

and now test array does not have "#4 element".

**2nd Ans**
Instead of Console.WriteLine use Console.Write .

Answer (score 0):

For your edit. While flushing your o/p just do not flush the outdated element. Using some conditional operator.

Eg: 1. If you want to remove on the basis of array valve then use

```
string[] test = new string[5];
for(int x = 0; x <= test.Length - 1; x++)
{
    test[x] = "#" + (x + 1) + " element";
    If (test[x] == "Desired value which you dont want to show")
    Console.WriteLine(test[x]);
}
```

2. If you want to remove on the basis of array position then use

   ```
   string[] test = new string[5];
   for(int x = 0; x <= test.Length - 1; x++)
   {
       test[x] = "#" + (x + 1) + " element";
       If (x == "Desired index which you dont want to show")
          Console.WriteLine(test[x]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

While what the others wrote is correct, sometimes you have an array, and you don't want to have a `List<>`...

```
public static void Main()
{
    string[] test = new string[5];

    for(int x = 0; x < test.Length; x++)
    {
        test[x] = "#" + (x + 1) + " element";
        Console.WriteLine(test[x]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    RemoveAt(ref test, 3);
    // Or RemoveRange(ref test, 3, 1);

    for(int x = 0; x < test.Length; x++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test[x]);
    }
}

public static void RemoveAt<T>(ref T[] array, int index)
{
    RemoveRange(ref array, index, 1);
}

public static void RemoveRange<T>(ref T[] array, int start, int count)
{
    if (array == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    }

    if (start < 0 || start > array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("start");
    }

    if (count < 0 || start + count > array.Length)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
    }

    if (count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    T[] orig = array;
    array = new T[orig.Length - count];
    Array.Copy(orig, 0, array, 0, start);
    Array.Copy(orig, start + count, array, start, array.Length - start);
}
```

Two simple methods to remove elements of an array (`RemoveAt` and `RemoveRange`), with full example of use.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have fixed size, so if you want add or remove element from them you need to deal with resizing. Therefore in C# it is recommended to use Lists instead (they deal with it themselves).[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which) is nice post about Arrays vs Lists.

But if you really want to do it with Array or have a reason for that, you could do it this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        //destination array
        int[] newArray = new int[myArray.Length-1];

        //index of the element you want to delete
        var index = 3;

        //get and copy first 3 elements
        Array.Copy(myArray, newArray, index);

        //get and copy remaining elements without the 4th
        Array.Copy(myArray, index + 1, newArray, index, myArray.Length-(index+1));


        //Output newArray
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("#{0} {1}", i + 1, newArray[i]));                        
            if (!(i == newArray.Length - 1))
            {
                sb.Append(", ");
            }
        }
        Console.Write(sb.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See My solution... let me know if does helps...

```
class Program
    {

        // this program will work only if you have distinct elements in your array

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] test = new string[5];
            for (int x = 0; x <= test.Length - 1; x++)
            {
                test[x] = "#" + (x + 1) + " element";
                Console.WriteLine(test[x]);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Program p = new Program();
            test = p.DeleteKey(test, "#3 element"); // pass the array and record to be deleted
            for (int x = 0; x <= test.Length - 1; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test[x]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public string[] DeleteKey(string[] arr, string str)
        {
            int keyIndex = 0;
            if (arr.Contains(str))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i] == str)
                    {
                        keyIndex = i; // get the index position of string key
                        break; // break if index found, no need to search items for further
                    }
                }

                for (int i = keyIndex; i <= arr.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1]; // swap next elements till end of the array
                }
                arr[arr.Length - 1] = null; // set last element to null

                return arr; // return array
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```