# How to remove item from string array in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an array of string . I want to remove an item from string. HOw i can do this.

```
string []values = User.Split(';');
```

Suppose values contains "1","2","3","4"

I want to delete or remove item "2" from values. How i can do this. Is there built in function in C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You are right @JenishRabadiya

Comment: Possible duplicate of.... wait.... just google your title https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+remove+item+from+string+array+in+C%23%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Backs hmm you are right. Thanks for pointing it out but now I won't be able to edit that comment so would delete that comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Array is [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) object. So, you can't remove from array. You can create new array without this value using [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
values = values.Where(o=> o != "2").ToArray();
```

Or, you can create [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) and remove from list:

```
List<string> values = User.Split(';').ToList();
values.Remove("2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myArray = myArray.Where(w => w != myArray[2]).ToArray();
```

Comment: you can't be sure, that `myArray[2] == "2"`