# Removing a specific string from an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create selling feature where if you use the sell command and write one of the items you want to sell from your inventory(array) then it will remove the item from the array and add some money to your balance. How do I remove a specific string from an array? For example, I want to say that I want to remove the string "Carp" without specifying "inventory[0]".

```
long balance = 100;

string[] inventory = {"Carp", "Laptop", "Mobile"}
Console.WriteLine("What do you want to sell?"

string sellingItem = Console.ReadLine();

if(sellingItem.Equals("Carp")
{
  Console.WriteLine("Selling Carp");
  balance = balance+15;
  
  //

}
```

I tried to search for solutions but none of them were able to full fil my criteria.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you use List<string> instead of array, you can remove item from by doing inventory.Remove("Carp");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove item from string array in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33031018/how-to-remove-item-from-string-array-in-c)

Comment: you should also mention if there are duplicate items in the array or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq.

For example

```
inventory = inventory.Where(x=> x != "Carp").ToArray();
```

Note this will create a new array instance.

Generally I find working with `List<>` easier than arrays in which case you can use and maintain the same collection object:

```
inventory.RemoveAll(x=> x == "Carp");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-7.0