# Poker Game: How to Add/Remove Cards from player's hand when using enums?

Tags: c#, enums

I'm creating a poker game am I am trying to figure out how to hold certain cards in the player's hand while replacing the one's the player selects to be replaced.

tl;dr: How do I allow the player to pick and choose which cards to hold and which cards get replaced witha new card?

My Code so far:

Deal class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PROG120_FINALPROJECT
{
    class Deal 
    {
        int CardHNum = 1;//Player's membership card number

    private DeckofCards Deck = new DeckofCards();

    private Card[] PlayerHand;
    private Card[] ComputerHand;
    private Card[] SortPHand; //sorted player hand
    private Card[] SortCHand; // sorted computer hand


    public Deal()
    {
        var selected = this.Deck.GetDeck.Take(10).Select((x, n) => new { x, n }).GroupBy(x => x.n % 2, x => x.x).ToArray();
        this.PlayerHand = selected[0].ToArray();
        this.ComputerHand = selected[1].ToArray();
    }

    public void DealSetup()
    {
        sortCards();
        evaluateHands();
    }

    public void sortCards()
    {
        this.SortPHand = this.PlayerHand.OrderBy(x => x.CardValue).ToArray();
        this.SortCHand = this.ComputerHand.OrderBy(x => x.CardValue).ToArray();
    }

    public void evaluateHands()
    {
        //create player's computer's evaluation objects (passing Sorted hand to constructor)
        HandEvaluator playerHandEvaluator = new HandEvaluator(SortPHand);
        HandEvaluator computerHandEvaluator = new HandEvaluator(SortCHand);

        //get the player's and computer's handj
        Hand playerHand = playerHandEvaluator.EvaluateHand();
        Hand computerHand = computerHandEvaluator.EvaluateHand();

        //display each hand
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nPlayer's Hand: " + playerHand);
        foreach (var card in PlayerHand)
        {
            Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
///Where I tried to remove/add card to hand
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the cards you would like to remove as such: 1,2");
        string HandHolder = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] splitHandHolder = HandHolder.Split(',');
        int[] splitHandHolderint = Array.ConvertAll(splitHandHolder, int.Parse);
        {
            ///remove at only works for Lists- find another way

            playerHand.RemoveAt(i - 1);
            int next = r.Next(0, deck.Count);
            Card c = deck[next];
            playerHand.Insert(i - 1, c);
        }


        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("\nThis is your new hand."+ playerHand);
        CardHNum = 1;
        foreach (var card in PlayerHand)
        {
            Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n");
        }




        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n\nComputer's Hand: " + computerHand);

        foreach (var card in ComputerHand)
        {
            Console.Write(card.CardValue.ToString());
            Console.Write(" of ");
            Console.Write(card.CardSuit.ToString());
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
        //evaluate hands
        if (playerHand > computerHand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
        }
        else if (playerHand < computerHand)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
        }
        else //if the hands are the same, evaluate the values
        {
            //first evaluate who has higher value of hand
            if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total > computerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total)
                Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
            else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total < computerHandEvaluator.HVs.Total)
                Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
            //if both hanve the same poker hand 
            // player with the next higher card wins
            else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard > computerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard)
                Console.WriteLine("Player WINS!");
            else if (playerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard < computerHandEvaluator.HVs.HighCard)
                Console.WriteLine("Computer WINS!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Draw, no one wins!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Edit: Removed not needed/ confusing information.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. What does the data structure of the card have to do with removing it from a list?

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this. I'm essentially asking how would I allow the player to pick and choose which cards they keep and which cards in there hand get replaced with new cards.

Comment: If you're talking about this `Card[]`, no that is not an enum, that is an array of Card, which could be a class or enum, etc. [**How to delete an element from an array in C#**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/497005/342740)

Comment: Edited the code to add a comment (the comment is "where I tried to.." ) playerHand.RemoveAt won't work because I'm not using a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the cards you would like to remove as such: 1,2");
string HandHolder = Console.ReadLine();
string[] splitHandHolder = HandHolder.Split(',');
int[] splitHandHolderint = Array.ConvertAll(splitHandHolder, int.Parse);

var updated = playerHand.Where((x, n) => !splitHandHolderint.Contains(n + 1)).ToArray();
playerHand = updated.Concat(deck.Take(5 - updated.Length)).ToArray();
```

That keeps the cards that weren't in `splitHandHolderint` and then "tops up" the hand from `deck` with `deck.Take(5 - updated.Length)`.

The issue you have with using `r.Next(0, deck.Count)` to add cards to the hand is that you are likely to get cards that have already been used. You really need to use the type `Stack<Card>` rather than `Card[]` to model your `Deck`.

My solution above assumes that `deck` is **randomly** sorted, i.e. shuffled, already and doesn't contain any cards that have currently been used.