# deleting an item user provided from an array

Tags: c#

I am working on a project, and I am finding it hard to delete entire row associated with the item id no user wants to be deleted.

```
//a bunch of codes that includes switch and struct statement and a while statement before this snip of code I just pasted                          

Console.Write("Please enter an item ID No: ");
string id = Console.ReadLine();
int itemidnotodelete = int.Parse(id);
bool iDelete = false;

for (int i = 0; i < ItemCount; i++)
{
    if (item[i].itemIDNo == itemidnotodelete)
    {
        iDelete = true;
        //Delete the item if you found it
        item[i + 1].itemIDNo = item[i + 1];

        //Reset the count to show a new count for your list
        ItemCount = ItemCount - 1;
        //(Note: your list is now reduced by one item)
```

I know you can't just delete from an array. I want to shift, say if I found the item id  the user provides, I move the entire row associated with that ID (for each id there are several column) to the last and then the entire column in my data moves up one. I mean it so easy in words but I am finding it hard to put in code.

Comment: So you don´t want delete entities from your db? I can´t see why, but anyway you can also set a flag on the entity marking it active or non-active and then show only those who have the flag set to active.

Comment: Do you want to delete or not delete? Why is your variable called "itemidnotodelete"? What are you trying to achieve? Take an item according to the ID, move it to the end of the array and shift everything in the array to close the "hole". ?

Comment: @AlexeiFimine I want to delete. The variable "itemidnotodelete" is what the user types. I am trying to achieve a deletion of an entire row, if the ID number is found. For example you have a column of (itemID, Type, Placesfound, Uses) in row 1 i.e the header, and under that in row 2 you have (123, plates, ceramic, kitchen, eating), in row 3 you have (456, headphones, electronics, entertainment) and row 4, row 5 etc. So lets say I want to delete itemID 456? How do I shift the entire row of itemID 456 to  the last position in my array and then shrink it. That's my problem.

Comment: @AlexeiFimine The header (itemID, Type, Placesfound, Uses) are struct of itemlist. So var item = new itemlist [10]

Comment: Can anyone tell me if I am getting warm. Since I have a struct, I would have to create a constructor if I want to delete/replace the deleted position (i) with a new position (i + 1).

Comment: @user124473  Now again, when you say "So lets say I want to delete itemID 456? How do I shift the entire row of itemID 456 to the last position in my array and then shrink it. "  what do you mean exactly? Do you want to delete the row with ID 456 or do you want to move it to the end of the list  while shifting the whole array one record?

Comment: @user124473 also are you required to use arrays? Are you constrained to a single array? Is this an array manipulation exercise or a real life problem? We're not going to tell anyone :)

Comment: @AlexeiFimine hahah its an assignment. And yes I want to delete the entire row with ID 456. And since I haven't learned any other method, I am constrained to a single array (and it is an array manipulation exercise)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that does what I think you need to be done. It goes and removes your record from the array, shifts everything one position and puts your record to the end of the array. I used some of your code. If stick all this into the "main" of you console app it will work. This is O(n) time / O(n+1) space - in case you'll need to justify your choice of algorithm :)

```
struct MyWreck
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Desc;
        }
        static int itemCount = 10;
        static MyWreck[] items = new MyWreck[10];

        public static void PrepareArray()
        {
            var seed = 400;
            for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                items[i] = new MyWreck { Id = seed + i, Desc = "Description " + i };
            }

        }

        public static void DeleteFromArray()
        {

            PrepareArray();

            Console.Write("Please enter an item ID No: ");
            string id = Console.ReadLine();
            int itemidnotodelete = int.Parse(id);
            bool iDelete = false;

            var removedWreck = new MyWreck();

            for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].Id == itemidnotodelete)
                {
                    iDelete = true;
                    removedWreck = items[i];

                }
                if (iDelete)
                {
                    if (i < itemCount - 1)
                    {
                        items[i] = items[i + 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        items[i] = removedWreck;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thik this is what I am looking for. I have a question tho, why did you declare a var removeWreck?

Comment: Because you need to store your removed record somewhere while you're shifting the rest of the array. Once all records are shifted you take your "deleted" record and put it at the end of the array. 

another solution would be to make your array longer by 1 and store your deleted record there, but I find it messier in terms of dealing with the index.

Comment: If however you do not need to store that deleted record at the end, then simply remove everything that has to do with "removedWreck" variable.

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking and definitely point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, you cannot delete from an array (or add to it for that matter).

The correct solution is to use another container if you need to add/remove items.

The most common container for adding and removing in .NET is a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I haven't been taught List, and I bet that would be easier. I am just making do with what I have be taught. Please see my comment to @AlexeiFimine

Comment: In the code, item is declared as an array of struct. I would appreciate hints.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way I know would be linq e.g.:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2 };
int numToRemove = 4;
numbers = numbers.Where(val => val != numToRemove).ToArray();
```

If you have other arrays of complex type you just have to change the .where Statement.

Comment: You mean short way to code, linq is not fastest way as far as I know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp here you can find several ways to do this.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak - well you are probably right - depends highly on the amount of items. I should have been more correct and say: "fastest way of implementing it" - sorry about the inaccurate statement

Comment: Nothing to be sorry, it is ok :) I could keep my comment as it may give some ideas, although you updated your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
item[i + 1].itemIDNo = item[i + 1];
```

i would change it to `item[i].itemIDNo = item[i + 1];` and pack it in a loop which iterates through the array until you are at size-1. then you can break. now oyu should have just overwritten the data you want to delete and shifted all the other data 1 row up

Comment: I would do that but "item" is initialized to a struct which contain the heading s  i.e itemIDNo, itemID, Type, Placesfound, Uses, that I am using to solve this problem. So I just need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Linq approach

```
item = item.Where(x => x.itemIDNo == int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())).ToArray();
ItemCount = item.Length; //or better replace ItemCount with item.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but you can copy the array into an another array. Something like this.

```
        int[] items = { 1, 3, 4, 9, 2 };
        int[] newItems = new int[items.Length-1];
        var itemtodelete = 4;
        int itemIndex=-1;
        int j = 0, k = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (items[i] == itemtodelete)
            {
                itemIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        while (j < items.Length - 1)
        {
            if (k != itemIndex)
            {
                newItems[j++] = items[k];
            }
            k++;
        }
```