# Wrong message because of for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a function which deletes a user from a group.

First it checks if there are any users in the group at all. Then in a for-loop it goes through all users and checks if the current user, which is typed in, exists in the group.

First time it works. It deletes the user. But in the second time the user doesn't exist anymore and it comes to the else statement.

How can I end the for-loop when the user is deleted?

Here is the code:

```
for (int y = 0; y < cognosGroup.members.value.Length; y++)
{
    //check if member[y] is the one that need to be deleted
    if (cognosGroup.members.value[y].searchPath.value == member[0].searchPath.value)
    {
        int lenght = cognosGroup.members.value.Length - 1;

        baseClass[] newMembers = new baseClass[lenght];
        int index = 0;
        baseClass obj = null;
        // go trough group
        for (int i = 0; i <= lenght; i++)
        {
            if (i != y)
            {
                //create user
                obj = cognosGroup.members.value[i];
                newMembers[index] = obj;
                index++;
            }
            else
            {
                this._messageText = "*Succesfully removed " + this.RemoveUsername.ToLower() + " from " + this.DataViewModel.GroupModel.SelectedGroup;
                this.ExHandling = new ExceptionHandling(this._messageText);
                this.MessageText = this.ExHandling.ExHandlingOkey;
            }
        }
        cognosGroup.members = new baseClassArrayProp();
        cognosGroup.members.value = newMembers;
        this.LogonModel.CBICMS.update(new baseClass[] { cognosGroup }, new updateOptions());
        y--;
    }
    else
    {
        this._messageText = "*" + this.RemoveUsername.ToLower() + " is not a user from " + this.DataViewModel.GroupModel.SelectedGroup;
        this.ExHandling = new ExceptionHandling(this._messageText);
        this.MessageText = this.ExHandling.ExHandlingError;
    }
}
```

Comment: `break` statement? Btw, this code can be rewritten into a single line. See: [How to delete an element from an array in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/496896/69809).

Comment: you could use break?

Comment: Seriously, don't do this, if you can do this: `members.value = members.value.Where(v => v.searchPath.value != item).ToArray();`. [*Code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live*](http://wiki.c2.com/?CodeForTheMaintainer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the return statement to exit the routine or continue to skip to the next iteration.

Comment: oh so easy. Thank you very much!

Comment: Return exits the function, break exits the loop you are in.