# c# split string

Tags: c#, android, arrays, xamarin

I have this code that splits a specific string.

```
str = "\n\nThis\nString\nis\nsplit\ninto\narray";
string[] delimiterChar = { "\n" };

var splitArray = str.Split(delimiterChar);
```

The split array is simple array of strings, but why isn't it possible to remove the first 2 item by using:

```
splitArray[0].remove();
splitArray[0].remove();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove empty entries, then just specify it in the split method. There is no need to remove them manually.

```
var splitArray = str.Split(delimiterChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you want to specifically remove certain specific elements, then you can convert the array (non-mutable) to a list (mutable), and work on it like:

```
var splitList = str.Split(delimiterChar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
splitList.RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of the solution which might get the desired result.

```
string str = "\n\nThis\nString\nis\nsplit\ninto\narray";
str = str.TrimStart('\n');
var splitArray = str.Split('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

> yes,but sometimes the string contains random string at the first 3 indexes..
>   so i want to split this simple string into Array via Split and remove .
>
> The split array is simple array of strings, but why isn't it possible to remove the first 2 items

Split it and then skip whatever number of items you wish using Linq:

```
// I am skipping 3 for example
var splitArray = str.Split(delimiterChar).Skip(3).ToList();
```

Make sure to add this to the list of using statements:

```
using System.Linq;
```