# How to remove variable of Specific Type from Object[] in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, removeall

I have an *array* of `Objects` type which have information of variable of different classes, say, `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

```
public object[] SelectedObjects { get; }
```

Now I am filtering the objects of `ClassB` which I need to remove from the array of `SelectedObjects`.

```
var selectedClassBObjects = SelectedObjects.OfType<ClassB>().ToList();
```

When I perform the operation of `Remove()` or `RemoveAll()`, it *does not do anything*.

Can anyone suggest me how to perform this operation?

I need to remove objects of `ClassB` because at a time only one object of `ClassB` can be present when user is trying to Highlight the objects on the canvas. First remove the `ClassB` objects then add the newly selected `ClassB` objects to `SelectedObjects[]`.

Comment: if you want to modify the collection, array is not a good choice; try `List<T>`: `public List<object> SelectedObjects {get;}`; then `SelectedObjects.RemoveAll(item => !(item is ClassB));`

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

You can't remove anything from an array, you will need to create a new one. If you want to exclude objects of type `ClassB` you can do:

```
SelectedObjects = SelectedObjects.Where(x => !(x is ClassB)).ToArray();
```

If you want a modifiable collection, `List<T>` is a better choice than an array.

Comment: `SelectedObjects {get;}` is *read only* property; `SelectedObjects =` probably (if it's not in the constructor) will not compile

Comment: yeah well, do I have to say everything?

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on *array* you can put the *backing field* explicitly:

```
private object[] m_SelectedObjects = new object[0];

public object[] SelectedObjects {
  get {
    return m_SelectedObjects;
  }
}

private void MyRemove() {
  // We can't modify read-only property but can operate with its backing field 
  m_SelectedObjects = m_SelectedObjects?.OfType<ClassB>()?.ToArray();
}
```

Another possibility is to change *array* `object[]` into `List<object>`:

```
public List<object> SelectedObjects { get; }

...

// We still can't assign SelectedObjects but we can modify the collection now
SelectedObjects?.RemoveAll(item => !(item is TypeB));
```