# c# How to to remove line in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

My method looks like this:

```
void OldOnesToFile(List<Student> students)
{
    string[] lines = new string[students.Count];

    int i = 0;

    foreach (Student student in students)
    {
        if (student.Course > 1)
            lines[i] = String.Format(
               "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}", 
                students[i].LastName, 
                students[i].FirstName, 
                students[i].Birthday, 
                students[i].StudId, 
                students[i].Course, 
                students[i].MobileNumber, 
                students[i].Freshman);
            else 
                lines[i] = remove //Something like that??

            i++;
        }

        File.WriteAllLines(@"senbuviai.txt", lines);
    }
```

Take a look where I've *left a comment*. How should I write code that if a student's course is not bigger than `1`, that line would *delete* or would disappear because I got something like that.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an element from an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `if (student.Course > 1) { lines[i] = ...; i++ }`. increment only if you added a student. But using lists is more flexible as they grow dynamically.

Comment: In your code sample there is no need to remove data from the array, you can just generate the file of those matching the condition without removing them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why using *array* at all? `List<string>` is by far more convenient:

```
void OldOnesToFile(List<Student> students)
{
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    foreach (Student student in students)
    {
        if (student.Course > 1)
            lines.Add(String.Format(...));
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(@"senbuviai.txt", lines);
}
```

or even *Linq*:

```
 void OldOnesToFile(List<Student> students)
 {
     File.WriteAllLines(@"senbuviai.txt", students
       .Where(student => student.Course > 1)
       .Select(student => string.Format(...)));  
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but your code works vice versa in both ways, it writes in to the file all 1 course students, not bigger than 1, student.Course > 1 i think it's not working.

Comment: @Lukas Velička: When shall we write student into the file? In case he/she has *more* than `1` course? `student.Course > 1`

Comment: We shall write student's all info to the file when his course is more than 1.

Comment: @Lukas Velička: OK, let's dfebug. Put *breakpoint* on `lines.Add(String.Format(...));` line, execute the routine, *wait* for stop and *inspect* `student.Course`

Comment: What do you mean ? I can insert all code there if you need

Comment: @Lukas Velička: I mean *debugging*: run the routine under VS built in debugger. Put a *breakpoint* (<kbd>F9</kbd>), execute the routine, wait until it *stops* and with a help of *Immediate Window* (main menu -> Debug -> Windows -> Immediate) inspect `student.Course` value

Comment: Okay i have done debugging, everything seems good, course values are correct, it seems that if function just ignores the statement that it should add line if course is more than 1, it just do it. And i have done testing a bit, i have changed every students in the data file course to 1 and then after running the code, all students have been writing to file, so it seems the if works like student.Course == 1

Comment: @Lukas Velička: If `if` had been *that wrong* we wouldn't use C# *at all*. Try debuging with your testing data file: put a breakpoint, inspect `student.Course` value, then `student.Course > 1` value use F10 and F11 to line by line execution

Comment: Yes, i have done this, i don't understand, anything. I have tested, what just saw is weird, the program even not paying attention to student.course. It pays attention to student.freshman which is true or false, if its true on my data file, then they add that file, it works like this, even if it written                 if (student.Course > 1)
It works like that.                 if (student.Freshman == true)