# How to remove an element from an array and move back the rest? (C#)

Tags: c#

Here's an example of an array

```
int[] N = new int[]{1,0,6,0,3,4};
for (int i = 0; i < N.Length; i++){
    if (N[i] == 0){
    //remove N[i] and moveback everything }
        foreach (string i in N) {
            Console.Write("{0} ", i + " ");
}
```

Example output would be

```
1 6 3 4
```

Comment: Short answer: You can't. You may create a new array and copy the existing elements. But doing what you suggest is like erasing a word from a printed book and move all following words back.

Comment: If you need to change the length of your collection you should be using a `List`, not an array.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and we can help with why that isn't working.  Asking "How do I do this?" without showing any attempt on your side is not a great question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete an element from an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Filtering to create new array

```
N = N.Where(x => x != 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Yeah. Since he insists on arrays, the above can also be written `N = Array.FindAll(N, x => x != 0);`

Comment: This is the right solution, I didn't read the question correctly +1

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a nice fit for a generic extension method, and [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2) to have a nice fast solution

***Note*** : This recreates an array.

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static T[] RemoveElement<T>(this T[] source, int index)
      where T : new()
   {

      if(index >= source.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

      // create new array
      var result = new T[source.Length - 1];
      // Copy the first part
      Array.Copy(source, 0, result, 0, index);
      // Copy the second part
      Array.Copy(source, index+1, result, index, source.Length - (index+1));

      return result;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
int[] N = new int[]{1,0,6,0,3,4};
var result = N.RemoveElement(1);
```

**Example**

```
public static void Main()
{
   int[] N = new int[]{1,0,6,0,3,4};

   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", N.RemoveElement(1)));
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", N.RemoveElement(0)));
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", N.RemoveElement(5)));
}
```

**Output**

```
1,6,0,3,4
0,6,0,3,4
1,0,6,0,3
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/qTQBAY)

---

**Additional Resources**

[Copy(Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified
>   source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the
>   specified destination index. The length and the indexes are specified
>   as 32-bit integers.

Comment: Nice solution, but he ask to remove by value not index, so your solution need some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
int[] N = new int[]{1,0,6,0,3,4};

var foos = new List<int>(N);
int indexToRemove = 1;
foos.RemoveAt(indexToRemove);
N = foos.ToArray();

foreach(int elem in N )
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
```

FYI: for high performance/frequent access, linq is not recommended.