# Delete a number from Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list

I'm trying to delete a number from an array. I've tried following a tutorial and the method deletes the number I enter and if there are duplicates it deletes the first duplicate number, however it always shows 0 at the start, even though 0 isn't a number in the array. E.g. say I have a list of numbers 1, 12, 44, 55, 66, 17, 8, 4, 12, 70 and I delete number 44, the output is: 0, 1, 12, 55, 66, 17, 8, 4, 12, 70. I can't work out why the 0 is appearing and how to get rid of it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace deletenumber
{
class Program
{
    public class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node next;
    };

    static Node add(Node head, int data) 
    {
        Node temp = new Node();
        Node current;
        temp.data = data;
        temp.next = null; 

        if (head == null) 
            head = temp;
        else
        {
            current = head;
            while (current.next != null)
                current = current.next;
            current.next = temp; 
        }
        return head;
    }

    static void print(Node head)
    {
        while (head != null) 
        {
            Console.Write(head.data + " "); 
            head = head.next;
        }
    }

    static Node List(int[] a, int n)
    {
        Node head = null; 
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            head = add(head, a[i]);
        return head;
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int n = 10;
        Random r = new Random(); 
        int[] a;
        a = new int[n + 1];
        a[0] = 0;
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            a[i] = r.Next(1, 100);

        Node head = List(a, n);
        Console.WriteLine("List = ");

        print(head);
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("What number do you want to delete?");
        int item = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

        int index = Array.IndexOf(a, item);
        a = a.Where((e, k) => k != index).ToArray();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: a[0] = 0; in static main?

Comment: If I'm not confused, you put a[0] = 0, and did not overwrite it

Comment: `a[0] = 0;` - your array always has that zero in it...however in your List function, you start at index 1, so you never see the "0" the first time around (when you call `print(head)`, but you *do* see it when you dump the array to the console later on

Comment: Btw on [How to delete an element from an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/)

Comment: But how do I change it so it doesn't show 0

Comment: use a list not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to print `0` I don't know why you're adding it in the first place, but notice the two different ways you "print" the array.

The first method (the `print` function) starts at item 1 (skipping the "first" element at index 0) and loops until the end.

The second just `join`s *all* elements (including the "first" element) of the array and prints the resulting string.

So how do you skip the zero? There are many ways:

- Don't add zero in the first place (and change your `print` loop to start at 0)
- Use the same print method that loops from 1
- `Skip` the first item in your array:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a.Skip(1)));
  ```

Personally, I would just use the same method for printing both times, and I would also use [`Array.RemoveAt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.removeat) to "delete" the item rather then creating a new array by using `Where().ToArray()`.