# Removing array elements per draw C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, while-loop

everyone. For starters this is my first C# code as a college freshmen(Still a noob here), I apologize in advance in my English. So basically I've been trying to solve this for 5 hours already, I'm real bad at this and this is my first ever post for help here.

So this code's goal is:

1.input an integer 1-2. 1 is draw and 2 is exit

2.once the draw starts, the code will get a random index inside that name array

3.then the random picked element should be removed in that name array in order to get new random element.

4.the process repeats until non of the four names appear no more when printed.

```
using System;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            bool isTrue = true;
            while (isTrue)
            {
                
                //user choices
                Console.WriteLine("[1]Draw\n[2]Exit\n");

                //the input
                Console.Write("Enter action: ");
                int choices = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                
                //array of names
                string[] names = {"Mr. Albert", "Mr. Joshua", "Mr. Bernard", "Mr. Raphael"};

                //for random generating of names
                Random rand = new Random();
                int randNames = rand.Next(names.Length);
                
              
                //Draw
                if(choices == 1){
                    Console.WriteLine("Congrats "+names[randNames]);
                    names[randNames] = " ";
        
                    for(int i=0; i < names.Length; i++){
                        Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
                    }
                    
                }
                else if(choices == 2){
                    isTrue = false;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

So my main problem is here in this code with the given array of names

```
string[] names = {"Mr. Albert", "Mr. Joshua", "Mr. Bernard", "Mr. Raphael"};
```

In this part of the code, which I was having a hard time figuring out

```
if(choices == 1){
   Console.WriteLine("Congrats "+names[randNames]);
          names[randNames] = " ";
   for(int i=0; i < names.Length; i++){
          Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
   }
```

What I did here is whenever I draw the picked numbers here should turn into `" "`that or just make it look empty as I draw and draw three times. I tried to search this problem too, but no luck.

the results would look like this:

```
[1]Draw 
[2]Exit 

Enter action: 1
Congrats Mr. Albert

Mr. Joshua
Mr. Bernard
Mr. Raphael
[1]Draw
[2]Reset
[3]Exit

Enter action: 1
Congrats Mr. Joshua
Mr. Albert

Mr. Bernard
Mr. Raphael
[1]Draw
[2]Reset
[3]Exit

Enter action:
```

You could see in the result that they are not there, but in the next draw they still exist.
Hope someone could help me, Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you actually want to remove the entry from the array, it would be easier to instead use a `List<string>`  which supports removing/adding entries. A array needs to be re-created to remove items, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks, I'll take note of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your array before while loop:

```
string[] names = {"Mr. Albert", "Mr. Joshua", "Mr. Bernard", "Mr. Raphael"};
while (isTrue)
{
   //do your stuff
}
```

Right now, you edit your array and on the next iteration declare new array, which is unedited.

Comment: Thank you so much, never thought that before.

Comment: if it solved your problem, please mark it as an answer.