# Remove an element from an index array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

if from an array like this one

```
string[] arr={"a", "b"};
```

Can i modify it in this way?

```
arr={"a"};
```

Comment: this is a duplicate of this issue : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an element from an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the following different ways:

1)

```
var idx = 1;
arr = arr.Where((s, i) => i != idx).ToArray();
```

2. 

```
arr = arr.Where(s => s != "b").ToArray();
```

3. 

```
var filter = {"b"};

arr = arr.Except(​filter);
```

Comment: Welcome my friend

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
arr = new string[] { arr[0] };
```