# How to remove specific Array value like this example?

Tags: c#

I want to remove the value "4" in array.

`["5" , "4" , "10" , " "]`

to

`["5" , "10" , " "]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an element from an array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496896/how-to-delete-an-element-from-an-array-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the specific position of the array you can do something like this:

```
string[] someArray = {"5", "4", "10", ""};
someArray = someArray.Where(w => w != someArray[1]).ToArray();
```

if you don't you can convert to a list and search for anything and then convert back to array if needed:

```
string[] someArray = {"5", "4", "10", ""};
List<string> list = new List<string>(someArray);
list.Remove("4");

someArray = list.ToArray();
```

I saw you asked for function, so here is how you can make some functions I guess too:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] someArray = {"5", "4", "10", ""};
    var myNewArray = ArrayValueRemove(someArray, "4");
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public string[] ArrayValueRemove(string[] anArray, string valueToRemove)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>(anArray);
    list.Remove(valueToRemove);

    anArray = list.ToArray();
    
    return anArray;
}
```

There's no error checking, but you get the point I imagine.

Comment: wow I finally solved the problem 
thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. be sure to flag answer as such then.

Comment: what flag answer meaning? 
can you explain me..?
sorry 

Comment: @2222 he meant the gray check mark at the top left of his question. You are saying that the answer helped you.

Comment: @2222 There is a checkmark you can click on left of my answer.

Comment: Is this right? I checked on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

(LINQ)

```
    string[] numbers = {"5", "4", "10", " "};
    string stringToRemove = "4";
    numbers = numbers.Where(val => val != stringToRemove).ToArray();
```