# refresh array element

Tags: c#, .net

i am using array control in which i am saving value one by one.

now i have to delet one of the element and refresh it simultaneuosly.

for example....

```
string[] arr= new string(25);

arr[0]="A";
arr[1]="B";
arr[2]="C"; and so on....
```

now after deleting second element via `arr[1]=null;`

i want refreshed array like mentioned below...

```
arr[0]="A";
arr[1]="C"; and so on....
```

please help...

thanks in advance,,,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array

Comment: to make it more clear i am using Image array and to give you all general idea about my prob i used above example

Comment: @neerajMAX: Why does it matter what type of aray you are using?

Comment: got it... but what was the need to devote my question.. One cant think exact all the time... :(

Comment: If you're happy with one of the answers here, it's polite to click accept ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you should be using a `List<string>` rather than an array, this would give exactly the functionality you are describing.

Although arrays can be resized (thanks @Austin Brunkhorst), this is not "cheap" and you would you would need to move everything around yourself.

It should be noted, that with lots of inserts and removes Lists can get very inefficient, so you'd be better off with a `LinkedList<string>`. These have advantages and disadvantages. Google `linked list` for more info.

Comment: Arrays can dynamically be resized using `Array.Resize<T>()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to resize arrays, you have to create a new and copy all elements from the old to the new one.

```
arr = arr.Where(s => s != null).ToArray();
```

If you would use a `List<string>` you could use methods like [`List.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cd666k3e.aspx) or [`List.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5cw9x18z.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

When you have a static data amount you should use Array, BUT when you have dinamic data amount you should use List<>.

Answer (score 2):

If you'll be adding/deleting entries at arbitrary positions in your collection a lot, you'd be better off using a `LinkedList<string>` instead

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Array you can go with List

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(5);
list.Add(7);
```

you will get more options like

[Contains](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-contains)

[Exists](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-exists)

[IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-indexof)

[For Removing the items](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list) you will get the functions like

[Remove](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-remove)
  ex: dogs.Remove("bulldog"); // Remove bulldog

[RemoveAt](http://www.dotnetperls.com/removeat)
  ex: list.RemoveAt(1);

[RemoveAll](http://www.dotnetperls.com/removeall)