# Can not delete an elment from the array via lists C#

Tags: c#

This method doesn't work at all:

```
    public static void Delete(ref Prot[] pack, Prot prot)
    {
        var temp = new List<Prot>(pack);
        temp.Remove(prot);
        pack = temp.ToArray();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to have `pack` array be updated with the `prot` item removed? EDIT: If so, you forgot to assign it back to your `ref` parameter: `pack = temp.ToArray();`

Comment: You might find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/457501/4086

Comment: Sorry there's  `pack = temp.ToArray();` of course. But It doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Does `Prot` implement `IEquatable`? Does `temp.Remove(prot)` return true or false?

Comment: No It doesn't. So I suppose that where's my mistake.

Comment: check out my edits and http://ideone.com/vOZoYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `Prot` needs to override the `Object.Equals()` method. This is how `List<T>.Remove` works. From the documentation:

> If type `T` implements the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the equality comparer is the Equals method of that interface; otherwise, the default equality comparer is `Object.Equals`.

If you don't override `Object.Equals` it will just use the default implementation which checks for reference equality, not value equality.

So, `temp.Remove(prot);` was never removing any values. (This can be validated based on the return value of `Remove`. It returns `true` if it successfully removes a value, and `false` otherwise.

Here's a basic example: http://ideone.com/vOZoYI

---

Initial Answer (issue was a typo in question).

You are modifying a new object, a `List<Prot>`, not the `Prot[]` parameter. If you assign `pack` to the `List<Prot>.ToArray()` then it will remove it from the array passed in.

```
public static void Delete(ref Prot[] pack, Prot prot)
{
    var temp = new List<Prot>(pack);
    temp.Remove(prot);
    pack = temp.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, It's just misspelling. It still doesn't work.

Comment: It seems strange to me. In that object I've got just two int fields, so if they are equal to same fields of other object, objects are equal by default. Or isn't?

Comment: @user3149474 No. The default `Equals` implementation is reference equality, that is, both sides refer to the same object. `Object a, b; a = new Object(); b = a; // a.Equals(b) -> true` but `a = new Object(); b = new Object(); // a.Equals(b) -> false` since both `a` and `b` refer to different objects.