# remove members of array of class

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a `class` which contains an `array` of a second `class` just like this:

```
public class SimpayRecords
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public SimpayRecord[] records;
}
```

I have a third `class` which contains the `SimpayRecords` class. In this third `class` i want to loop through the `array` and remove unwanted items. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Records.Records.Length; i++)
{
    if (this.Records.Records[i].Date < this.LastTime)
      //remove TempRecords.Records[i]
}
```

how can i do it?

Comment: if you want to remove then you need list not array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use List to store your data, you could use Extension method as shown in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array)

```
public static class ArrayExtensions{
     public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] source, int index)
     {
        T[] dest = new T[source.Length - 1];
        if( index > 0 )
            Array.Copy(source, 0, dest, 0, index);

        if( index < source.Length - 1 )
            Array.Copy(source, index + 1, dest, index, source.Length - index - 1);

        return dest;
     }
}
```

Then you can use RemoveAt method as following:

```
Foo[] bar = GetFoos();
bar = bar.RemoveAt(2);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Array elements cant be removed. you need [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Make sure to reference `System.Collections.Generic`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Your class would be like.

```
public class SimpayRecords
{
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
    public List<SimpayRecord> records; // This is the List.
}
```

To remove from list

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Records.Records.Count; i++)
{
     if (this.Records.Records[i].Date < this.LastTime)
            this.Records.Records.RemoveAt(i--); // Removes the element at this index
}
```

Because List is Diffrent from normal array. so you have to learn about List. how to create them and how to work with them. so take a look at these.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Answer (score 1):

If reassigning a new array instance to `this.Records.Records` is not out of the question, you can do it with a simple `WHERE` condition (reversing your condition to a `>=`) in a LINQ query, like this:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

this.Records.Records = this.Records.Records.Where(r => r.Date >= this.LastTime).ToArray();
```

Comment: this will create another array. but its simpler :)

Comment: @M.kazem: the main advantage of simplicity is that it's easier to write bug free code.  Especially when performing deletes in a loop, it's easy to get it wrong, because when the deletes happen, if you don't adjust the index to account for the shifting of elements, then you can inadvertently skip certain elements in the list. hint, hint.

Comment: yes i agree with simplicity.however i forgot to reduce the counter when removing from, (i just fixed it now.) . i think OP should first learn List. so he/she will become better programmer :)