# Deleting array elements between X and Y

Tags: c#, arrays

How can we delete all array elements between 2 numbers?
For example :  The array is {2,6,3,6,8,2,7,2}
The user writes in two numbers, let's say 2 and 4.
That causes the program to delete every array elements between the 2nd and 4th position.
In this case, it deletes : 3,6,8

Comment: Is it an array or a list? With a list, you can just foreach. Or if you can create a new list / array, you can just use linq with skip and take. You can't resize an array.

Comment: It's an array, but can't we do anything about Array.Remove?

Comment: No. From the docs: "The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw NotSupportedException."

Comment: There are plenty of good solutions shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array - should be easy to adapt to remove the range instead of single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot delete items from an array. But you can create a new array that contains only the items that you want to keep. In your case you can use the following:

```
int[] array = {2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 2, 7, 2};
array = array.Where((_, i) => i < 2 || i > 4).ToArray();
```

By the way, if you use a List instead of an array, then you can remove items. Consider the following example:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() {2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 2, 7, 2};

for(int i = 4; i >= 2 ; i--)
{
    list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: I think your code not answering what this user is looking for. He is talking about a value within the array not the index of the array.

Comment: The question is talking about the 2nd and 4th positions. I think these are indexes.

Comment: Your first code works like a wonder. Can you explain the following line and what everything on it does?      
array = array.Where((_, i) => i < 2 || i > 4).ToArray();

Comment: `.Where` allows you to filter the items in the array. `(_, i) => i < 2 || i > 4` is a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that is used to specify which items should be allowed to pass. `i` in this case is the index of the item. You can replace `_` with any variable (like `z`) if you want to use the item value in the lambda expression. But since we don't care about the item value in our filter, we use `_` to say that we don't care about it.

Answer (score 1):

For lists, you can use `RemoveRange` to do exactly that. It’s just that instead of the (inclusive) end index, you need to pass the number of elements you want to delete. So for inclusive indexes `start` and `end` it would look like this:

```
list.RemoveRange(start, end - start + 1);
```

For arrays, you cannot really do this as once created arrays have a fixed size. If you really need an array, you could create a list from the array, remove the items, and then create an array again using `ToArray`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Yacoub Massad mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33714994/209259): You cannot delete items from an array. But you can create a new array that contains only the items that you want to keep. In this case I would use linq, it's super easy:

```
int[] array = {2, 6, 3, 6, 8, 2, 7, 2};
int x = 2;
int y = 4;

var array1 = array.ToList()
  .Take(x).Concat(array.ToList().Skip(x+y-1))
  .ToArray();


foreach(var i in array1)
{
  Console.Write(i);
  Console.Write(',');
}
```

Result:

> 2,6,2,7,2,

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RPx3tm)