# Delete object in List<string[]>

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following List:

```
List<string[]> filmlist = new List<string[]>();
```

The List contains Arrays like

```
string[] row = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", Convert.ToString(filmcounter) };
```

I want to delete an item in this List with a specific value of *filmcounter*.

Thanks!

Comment: in fact you want to delete an element from a string[] - google for that. Second, its not at all clear what you mean, show the list before and after the delete that you want

Comment: I think you are better suited with a `List<List<string>>` instead. Then you can use the `.Remove()` or `.RemoveAt()` methods.

Comment: I agree with the above use a list instead of array, but if you need to use an array google! Find the index of your value and remove that item here is a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array

Comment: Thanks @ja72! I will try this.

Comment: Do you wish to remove the filmcounter value from the row itself, or do you wish to remove the entire row that contains that filmcounter value from the filmlist?

Comment: @TVOHM The entire row. So that filmlist.count lowers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, like your additional comment clarifies, you want to delete a whole row that contains a specific 'filmcounter', you can do a few different things.

So using this example data:

```
List<string[]> filmlist = new List<string[]>()
{
    new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" },
    new[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "7" },
};
string filmcounter = "6";
```

To delete all rows that contain the specified filmcounter value:

```
filmlist.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains(filmcounter));
```

To only delete the first row that contains the specific filmcounter value:

```
int index = filmlist.FindIndex(x => x.Contains(filmcounter));
if (index != -1)
    filmlist.RemoveAt(index);
```

FindIndex in the second example will return the first index that contains the filmcounter value. We can then use this index to remove that row. It will return -1 if there are no matches.

Answer (score -3):

```
foreach(String value in filmlist){
    filmlist.Remove(value);
}
```

Check the C# method Remove(), it's exacly what you want.

Comment: You can't remove objects from a list while iterating through it.

Comment: not to mention this code would remove all items in the list.