# Find the n amount of highest values in an unsorted double (decimals) array with NO sorting

Tags: c#, arrays, double, user-input

Exercise:

The exercise requires that **NO** sorting is to be used e.g. descending order. I'm required to find the highest values from the array as is.

Example:

```
double[] arr = new double[5] {12.1, 5.9, 2.9, 6.8, 20.5}
```

Ask user for number = 3

I dont know how to do the calculations.

The highest values are

```
20.5, 12.1, 6.8
```

From what i understand i need to ask the user for a number. From that number create a way to search the array for the highest decimal number with **NO** sorting.

Comment: homework? seriously?

Comment: I thought i should be honest, i think i showed my understanding of what steps are required im just not confident in how i would go about implementing this as i have little experience outside int arrays. That is what calculations work for int arrays doesn't work for double arrays. I hate decimals argh.

Comment: okay. Let's see what I can think of!

Comment: @user5173426 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions asking about homework isn't against any rules

Comment: 1. sort array in descending order. 2. Loop for 0 to n to get n number of highest values

Comment: I'm required not to sort the array. Doesn't bubblesort defeat the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: If your requirment prohibits you to sort the array, please state so in your question

Comment: Doesn't the title say an unsorted array.

Comment: @nat1 does the answer help?

Comment: @user5173426  it does, cheers for the help.

Comment: @nat1 Check out my solution

Comment: @nat1, I updated my answer, with respect to your updated question

Comment: @nat1 I updated my answer with a solution that doesn't use LINQ

Comment: I'm just gonna post the link to the solution here https://dotnetfiddle.net/kgGgmf

Comment: @stasis Cheers.

Comment: @nat1 I updated my answer with a new solution without sorting the array, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sorting the `arr` array, but using a sorted additional collection containing the highest numbers found at any time:

```
double[] arr = new double[5] { 12.1, 5.9, 2.9, 6.8, 20.5 };

int num = 3;

var lst = new List<double>();

foreach (double n in arr)
{
    if (lst.Count < num)
    {
        lst.Add(n);
        lst.Sort();
    }
    else if (n >= lst[0])
    {
        lst[0] = n;
        lst.Sort();
    }
}

foreach (double n in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Without using any sort, but simply using a find-the-index-of-the-lowest-element function:

```
static int LowestIndex(double[] dbl)
{
    if (dbl.Length == 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int minIx = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < dbl.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dbl[i] < dbl[minIx])
        {
            minIx = i;
        }
    }

    return minIx;
}
```

then

```
double[] arr = new double[5] { 12.1, 5.9, 2.9, 6.8, 20.5 };

int num = 3;

var lst = new List<double>();
int minIx = -1;

foreach (double n in arr)
{
    if (lst.Count < num)
    {
        lst.Add(n);
        continue;
    }

    if (minIx == -1)
    {
        minIx = LowestIndex(arr);
    }

    if (n >= arr[minIx])
    {
        lst[minIx] = n;
        minIx = -1;
    }
}

foreach (double n in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Similar to the previous, but instead of sorting the `lst` list and considering the element at index `[0]` to be the lowest, we use a `LowestIndex` method... Note that to make everything more interesting, I "cache" when possible the `LowestIndex` result.

Third way, similar to the first one: `lst` is kept sorted "manually" (so when we add a new element to `lst`, we add it in the "right" position to keep `lst` sorted)... Much more complex :-) Note that I'm using [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_BinarySearch__0_) that has a "very interesting" way of returning the index when no exact match is found.

```
double[] arr = new double[] { 30, 1, 1, 12.1, 5.9, 2.9, 6.8, 20.5 };

int num = 3;

var lst = new List<double>();

foreach (double n in arr)
{
    int ix = lst.BinarySearch(n);
    if (ix < 0)
    {
        ix = ~ix;
    }

    if (ix == 0 && lst.Count == num)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (lst.Count == num)
    {
        lst.RemoveAt(0);
        ix--;
    }

    lst.Insert(ix, n);
}

foreach (double n in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code went over my head. Is this exercise considered hard? i'm a noob but i hoped i knew a little bit about c# but from your implementation i have a lot to learn.

Comment: @nat1 It isn't C#-hard... it is only "logically" hard. The second way doesn't use any advanced construct or function.

Comment: Cheers for all the examples.

Comment: You gave me different approaches for bubble sort, kudos to you +1

Comment: @xanatos, what are the reasons behind 0 upvotes to my solution, is list not a appropriate data structure to get max from array? or the way is wrong

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar Probably luck and formatting :-) I gave you a +1 :-)

Comment: :) is that my luck which stopped people to upvote my answer?  I thought my answer is not satisfying or missing any technical aspect. So I asked you a question. (It might be memory leak or something else) Just to learn from you

Comment: @Prasadtelkikar Badly formatted code seems "less correct" and "less tidy" than correctly formatted code. From a technical standpoint, duplicating the array in the list and then removing elements from the list seems to be counterintuitive (it is correct, but it doesn't "flow" in the mind of the reader)

Comment: @xanatos, thanks for your suggestions, I formatted my answer. To make it more readable and to understand easily I used List instead of bubble sort. BTW thanks again

Answer (score 3):

OP: *How would i code a program that will search a double array for the n amount of highest values. The n is determined by the user. For example a user inputs the number 3, the program is required to display the 3 highest values from the array.*

You could use LINQ `OrderByDescending` to order the array and then use LINQ `Take` to take the `n` highest values. I also added `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n)` to check if the user input is really an integer, if not the user is asked again to enter the number of highest elements he wants to extract from the array.

```
static void Main()
{
    double[] arr = { 2.11, 70.22, 15.67, 92.88, 105.91, 65.32, 40.25, 9.11, 22.09 };

    int n;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of highest elements you want to extract from the array:");

    while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of highest elements you want to extract from the array:");
    }

    double[] result = arr.OrderByDescending(x=>x).Take(n).ToArray();

    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6m24jB)**

`result` for `n=4`:

105.91

92.88

70.22

65.32

**After the OP Edited the question:** *From what i understand i need to ask the user for a number. From that number create a way to search the array for the highest decimal number with **NO sorting**.*

Here is a solution without sorting the initial array:

```
static void Main()
{
    int i,n;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of highest elements you want to extract from the array:");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of highest elements you want to extract from the array:");
    }
    double[] arr = { 12.1, 5.9, 2.9, 6.8, 20.5 };
    if (n > arr.Length)
        n = arr.Length;
    double[] result = new double[n];
    double max = 0;
    int k;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        max = arr[0];
        k = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (max < arr[i])
            {
                max = arr[i];
                k = i;
            }
        }
        result[j] = max;
        arr[k] = Double.MinValue;

        Console.WriteLine("Highest numbers: {0}", result[j]);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S0tqKA)**

Comment: Please checkout OP's updated question, he/she don't want to use Sorting.. Check mine as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

OP: *a program that will search an unsorted double array ie decimal numbers for the n amount of highest decimal values. The n is determined by the user. For example a user inputs the number 3, the program is required to display the 3 highest decimal values from the array.*

By using the LINQ  [`OrderByDescending`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZLkj.png) and [`Take`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KtLhH9) in such a way:

```
public static void Main()
{
        double[] array = new double[5] {12.1, 5.9, 2.9, 6.8, 20.5};

        Console.WriteLine("Enter input:");              // Prompt for input
        string input = Console.ReadLine();       

        int totalNums = Convert.ToInt32(input);

        //sort the array in descending order and get 
        //the desired number of elements out of it

        var topNumbers = array.OrderByDescending(i => i) 
                    .Take(totalNums);
        foreach (var x in topNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KtLhH9)

Comment: @nat1 indeed, if there is anything you do not understand in the answer above, I would be glad to explain! cheers

Comment: Please checkout OP's updated question, he/she don't want to use Sorting.. Check mine as well ;)

Comment: Your solution in one row:            `Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", array.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()))));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this approach as well

1.Sort your array in descending order.

2.Loop for first n element to get n highest numbers from array.

```
double[] arr = { 2.1, 70.1, 15.1, 92.1, 105.1, 65.1, 40.1, 9.1, 22.1 };
int n = 3; //This you can take it from user by using Console.ReadLine()
double[] result = arr.OrderByDescending(x=>x).ToArray();
//Result will contais {105, 92, 70, 65, 40, 22, 15, 9, 2}
//More readable to newbie 
Console.WriteLine("Top {0} elements from Array", n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      Console.Write(result[i]+" ");
    }

Output:
Top 3 elements from Array
105.1 92.1 70.1
```

[DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/35v8za)

---

If **you don't want to use sorting technique**, then you can try with following approach

```
double[] arr = { 2.1, 70.1, 15.1, 92.1, 105.1, 65.1, 40.1, 9.1, 22.1 };     
int n = 3;
List<double> list = new List<double>(arr);
Console.WriteLine("Top {0} elements", n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      double max = list.Max();  
      Console.WriteLine(max);
      list.Remove(max);
    }

Output:Top 3 elements
105.1
92.1
70.1
```

[DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SrFsjP)

Do not miss to add `System.Linq`, `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Comment: Would it be ok if i ask noob questions about your code?

Comment: @nat1 Sure, please ask

Comment: Is their a reason for why you're using a list to find the max numbers?

Comment: List provides `remove()` function, if you see my logic, I am storing max value into variable printing it and then removing it to get next max value. There is no built in function `remove ` is provided to int in C#

Comment: For array element removal, You need to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array

Comment: sorry forgot to refresh before posting again.