# Remove or trim zeros 0 at the end only of a float[] samples array

Tags: c#, arrays, trim

I am kind of new with C# and I was wondering if there is a function to remove specific values (0) at the end of an array of float?

For example:

```
float[] samples = {0.0, 4.0, 2.5, ..., 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

after the call I want my samples to be:

```
samples == {0.0, 4.0, 2.5, ..., 2.0}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Possibly related :[Remove element of a regular array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457453/4977870)

Comment: You might be better off working with a List<T>.

Answer (score 6):

I'd start by finding the final non-zero index:

```
int i = samples.Length - 1;
for( ; i >= 0; i--)
    if(samples[i] != 0.0F) break;
```

then I'd either copy that subset (`0`-`i` inclusive), or to avoid allocations I'd use a `Span<T>` to limit myself to that part without creating a new array:

```
var span = new Span<float>(samples, 0, i + 1);
```

Comment: `int i = samples.Length - 1; while(samples[i] == 0.0f) i--;` is another way to iterate over the array.

Comment: @D.Go nice, I like that

Comment: additional notes: if you need to *store* the range, use `Memory<float>` instead of `Span<float>`, and access the `.Span` when you need it; or if you're in old-school .NET: `ArraySegment<float>` would work too, but everything becomes manual

Comment: Clever use of span, but isn't it c# 7.2 feature?

Comment: @MihirDave indeed; if you look at the comment immediately above yours, I did suggest an alternative for the version-impaired

Answer (score 2):

```
float[] samples = { 0.0f, 4.0f, 2.5f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

var clean = new List<float>();
for (int i = 0; i <samples.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        if (samples[i] == 0.0f) clean.Add(samples[i]);
        continue;
    }
    if (samples[i] != 0.0f) clean.Add(samples[i]);
}

//clean.ToArray() = float[]
```

This may be better solution

```
float[] samples = { 0.0f, 4.0f, 2.5f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };

List<float> clean = samples.ToList();
for(int i=clean.Count-1; i>0; i--)
{
    if (clean[i] == 0.0f) clean.RemoveAt(i);
    else break;
}

//clean.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've tried this, it **works** for what I want but I'm not sure it is the simplest:

```
                float[] samples = new float[AudioFeedbackList[i].GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.samples * AudioFeedbackList[i].GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.channels];

            List<float> sampi = new List<float>();
            sampi.AddRange(samples);
            int j = sampi.Count;

            while (sampi[j - 1] == 0.0f)
            {
                j--;
            }

            List<float> newSampi = new List<float>();
            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                newSampi.Add(sampi[k]);
            }


            samples = newSampi.ToArray();
```

Thank you for the feedback!