# C#: Remove Many Elements from Array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

Please I have an array which filled with Number of elements, I want if specific Radiobutton is checked, specific elements removed from this array.... thank you

Comment: LINQ Except them

Comment: Please share some code you have already tried to write.

Comment: @Qwertyluk , I don't know the code of this process

Comment: Can you type the code >>>>> @CaiusJard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457453/remove-element-of-a-regular-array

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I fully understand what you mean, if you mean to delete specific element information after check radiobutton, I wrote a similar example.

If I misunderstood what you mean, please point it out and let me know.

**The code of xaml is as follows:**

```cs
<Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="textbox_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="92" Width="447" Background="#FFC9AD62"/>
        <Button x:Name="button_1" Content="Original array" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="158,173,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_1_Click"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton_1" Content="Delete less than 10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="273,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RadioButton_1_Checked"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RarioButton_2" Content="Delete more than 80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="414,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="RarioButton_2_Checked"/>
    </Grid>
```

**The code of xaml.cs is as follows:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace demo830 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            //Generate 100 random integers between 1 and 99 and fill the array
            //Array type is String array, size is 100
            string[] a = new string[100];
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
                a[i] = r.Next(1, 100).ToString();
            }
            //Invoke display function
            ViewArry(a);
        }

        //Display function
        private void ViewArry(string[] b) {
            this.textbox_1.Text="";//Initialize text before calling the output function
            foreach (var i in b) {
                this.textbox_1.Text = this.textbox_1.Text + i + " " ; 
            }
        }

        private void RadioButton_1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            string[] tmp = textbox_1.Text.Split(' ');//Here is "" as the demarcation
            //Delete the element at the specified position of tmp
            string[] c = tmp.Where(s => tmp.ToList().IndexOf(s) != tmp.Length-1).ToArray();

            //Delete values less than 10
            for (var i = c.Length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                if (c[i] != null) { 
                var item = Convert.ToInt32(c[i]);//Convert string to int
                    if (item < 10) {
                        //Delete the element at the specified position of c
                        string[] d = c.Where(s => c.ToList().IndexOf(s) != i).ToArray();
                    c = d;
                    }      
                }    
            }
            ViewArry(c);
        }

        private void RarioButton_2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            string[] tmp = textbox_1.Text.Split(' ');//Here is "" as the demarcation
            //Delete more than one blank data
            string[] c = tmp.Where(s => tmp.ToList().IndexOf(s) != tmp.Length - 1).ToArray();

            //Delete values greater than 80
            for (var i = c.Length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                if (c[i] != null) {
                    var item = Convert.ToInt32(c[i]);
                    if (item > 80) {
                        string[] d = c.Where(s => c.ToList().IndexOf(s) != i).ToArray();
                        c = d;
                    }
                }
            }
            //invoke the output function
            ViewArry(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The running effect of my demo is as follows:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please find the below-mentioned code

```
        List<string> lstString = new List<string>
        {
            new string("ABC"),
            new string("BCD"),
            new string("CDE"),
            new string("DEF"),
        };

        List<string> lstString1 = new List<string>
        {
            new string("AAA"),
            new string("BCD"),
            new string("ACD"),
            new string("DEF"),
        };

        lstString.RemoveAll(x=> lstString1.Contains(x));
```

Comment: OP is asking about array